# Vite assets still localhost on production server

Tags: laravel, vite

Vite path still localhost on Production Server

Can someone help me why my Vite Assets showing

```
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/css/app.css" />
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

instead of the builded assets in Laravel Vite?

Comment: did you build using ``npm run build`` command on your server?

Comment: How are you including the @vite tag in blade ?

Comment: All is fine before i reuploading my project.

*Note:
I can't use terminal on my server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you can't use the terminal on your server you need to run `npm run build` locally and make sure you upload all generated files as well.

Comment: I am still having this despite of running `npm run build` on local

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you accidentally transfered the file hot in the public directory. Delete it and it should work

The file is used when running the dev server but will break production

Comment: You have saved me :)

Comment: Yo! great one, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, I defined a new script for myself: `"production": "rm -f public/hot && npm run build"` in my Laravel application